# Button release does not work with xbindkeys

Tags: keyboard, mouse, xbindkeys, xte

Following [this tutorial](https://cubethethird.wordpress.com/2016/09/08/binding-mouse-keys-to-keyboard-keys-on-linux/), I'd like to map the page-forward button of the mouse (i.e. `b:9`) to `Shift_L`. However, using the tools `xte` and `xbinkeys` the button-down works, but the button-release does not. Using `xte` on its own, button-press and -release work. So it has to do something with my `~/.xbindkeys`.

Content of `~/.xbindkeys`:

```
# Page forward press
"xte 'keydown Shift_L'"
  b:9

# Page forward release
"xte 'keyup Shift_L'"
  b:9 + Release
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add  to the release (because you'll have shift pressed when your mb9 is down):

```
# Press shift with your mouse button 9:
"xte 'keydown Shift_L'"
  b:9

# Release shift with your mouse button 9 + shift
"xte 'keyup Shift_L'"
 Shift+Mod2+Shift_L + b:9 + Release
```

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to capture Super_L release but couldn't achieve untill Duncan's response.
Keypressed captured via:
Super_L

Key release captured via:
m:0x40 + Super_L + Release